Render a simple cube and access the image in python
I want to use bpy's API in Python to create a cube, render it, and access the rendered image as a numpy array (without save/load tmp file on disk). However, the image rendered by the following code is all zeros.
import bpy
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Clear existing objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Add a cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, 0))

# Add a camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(5, -5, 5), rotation=(1.1, 0, 0.785))
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.object

# Add a light source
bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='SUN', location=(5, -5, 5))

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 640
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 480
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100

bpy.context.scene.render.use_compositing = True
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links

# clear default nodes
for n in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(n)

# create input render layer node
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')

# create output node
v = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')
v.use_alpha = False

# Links
links.new(rl.outputs[0], v.inputs[0])

# render
bpy.ops.render.render()
render_result = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node']
pixels = np.array(render_result.pixels[:])

width = render_result.size[0]
height = render_result.size[1]
image_array = pixels.reshape((height, width, 4))
print(image_array.shape, image_array.dtype)

image_array = (image_array[:, :, :3] * 255).astype(np.uint8)
image = Image.fromarray(image_array)
image.save('cube_render.png')


How can I solve this problem?
System info

Ubuntu 22.04
Python 3.10
bpy 4.0.0


This has been asked several times. There is an old question with a few answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2170/107598 -- duplicates: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/311308/107598, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/88432/107598, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/323646/107598
